Create procedural triangles based on a given angle and length using geometry nodes
Create procedural triangles based on a given angle and length using geometry nodes.
I'm trying to create triangles given the angle and the length using geometry nodes but when I check the angle with the measure-it add-on / extension the angle doesn't match up.  Also the triangle changes z axis at certain points see blue arrows.
See animation and blend file below.






The Z axis change because of the Convex Hull node that is generating two faces. Because of numerical round-off, sometimes the upper face is Index 1, other times it is Index 0, with opposite normal in Z direction. And face 1 is deleted. Just mute this node, and the behavior is consistent. Furthermore, this node is useless as it is because the Mesh Circle node is already providing a "nice" single-face triangle...


@StefLAncien Thanks, any idea why the angles are off?


The angle is not what expected because the Sample Index nodes are set in Edge domain. So the "points" are at mid-edges. If the values defining the corners are $(100,50\sqrt{3})$, the displayed angle is 30° and correct. In Point domain, with sampled Index set to 1 instead of 2, the displayed angle is 60° and correct.

